# What is this question asking in laymans terms?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I am very new to proofs, and such, and I came across this question. I know what surjective and injective mean, but I don't understand what the question is even asking..

here it is. [image]

Comment: There appear to be two parts to your question -- (a) and (b). $\frac{d}{dx}$ is a function, and the question is asking whether the derivative function is injective in part (a) and surjective in part (b).

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dx}$ is a function that maps $P$ to $P$.

Hence the question if $\frac{d}{dx}$ is injective means, suppose we have $p,q \in P$ such that $\frac{d}{dx}p=\frac{d}{dx}q$, can you conclude that $p=q$?

The question is asking is it possible for two different functions to have the same derivative.

Comment: ...and it asks also in (b), if each polynomial is a derivative of some polynomial (surjectivity of the $d/dx$ function).